# direction property in Flex 3.6 is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, arabic

According to the documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html

property direction is avaliable from flex 3 but you have to use it from styles instead of direct use from text field like it is in flex 4.5

so i set:

```
<mx:Style>
    .myFontStyle {
    direction: "rtl";
    }
</mx:Style>
```

and:

`<mx:Label id="rtlLabel" styleName="myFontStyle"/>`

it is working when i use flex 4.6 but not for 3.6 any suggestions why or what i do wrong?
Or maybe you know any different way to deal with Arabic and Hebrew languages? it might be in pure actionScript

Answer (score 0):

Note that the documentation for the [direction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html#style%3adirection) style says:

> Note: This style only applies when an MX component specifies UIFTETextField as its textFieldClass.

So to make this work, you would also need to set the [textFieldClass](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html#style%3atextFieldClass) style:

```
<mx:Style>
    .myFontStyle {
    direction: "rtl";
    textFieldClass: ClassReference("mx.core.UIFTETextField");
    }
</mx:Style>
```

I just tried that as a test, but when using the Flex 3 SDK, this class is not included (at least in my environment) and I get a compile error saying it cannot find `UIFTETextField`. I don't use the Flex 3 SDK that often, so it could be that I just have an older version of it (I'm using this SDK: Flex 3.6A with Flash Builder 4.6). However, I have a feeling that this RTL functionality only exists when using the Flex 4 SDK ... so you can use an `<mx:Label />` with RTL text only when compiling w/the Flex 4 SDK -- though I'm not sure what the point of that would be.

I checked the code in my `<mx:Label />` class and I cannot find any references to the `direction` style or the `textFieldClass` style that the documentation says this class defines. So hopefully that just means my 3.6A SDK is just out of date.

However, if you look at the code for `UIComponent` in the Flex 4 SDK it talks about using the two styles mentioned above. But the `UIComponent` class in my Flex 3 SDK does not mention those styles at all. Maybe your Flex 3 SDK is better than mine, or perhaps someone else can explain this part.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to UIFTETextField in Flex3.6 and I can't use newer Flex 4 SDK because its old project and it contain a lot of solutions that would need to be rewrite for flex4, it would take too much time.